# Android Context Menu on double tap instead of longpress

Tags: android, contextmenu, long-press

In Android is it possible to register a View for context menu, so that the menu will show up when it is double tapped instead of when a long press action has been registered? I have a view with a scroll functionality. This view is also registered for a context menu. Whenever a scroll is performed on this view and the scroll action takes a certain amount of time the long press action is triggered and the context menu pops up. In order to avoid this situation I would like to make the context menu appear when the view is double tapped rather than when it is pressed long.

Comment: For that you need to set an onTouchListener and, in that, have a GestureLister listening for DoubleTaps

Comment: Ok so there's the method called openContextMenu(View v) for a particular view. However it says in the documentation, that the view should have been registered via registerForContextMenu(View v) before calling this method. Since I have to register the view first, the context menu will also pop up on longpress as always, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has run into this problem. What I ended up doing was to listen for the long press with the `GestureListener`. Once the long press event is triggered, I register the `view` for a context menu with `registerForContextMenu(View v)`, then call `openContextMenu(View v)`.

And in order to not have the context menu pop up and interfere with the long press event, I overrode the `onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu)` method, in which I call `unregisterForContextMenu(View v)` passing the `view` that I earlier registered.